# HtmlAgilityPack - How to get url path after redirect

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get a Url full path after it's doing redirect, simply here is the code:

```
 var documentx = new HtmlWeb().Load(textBox1.Text);
```

Where the **textbox1.text** value is "https://xxxx.org/file/download"

so after i run that code in real it's redirect and change the structure to:

```
https://xxxx.org/file/ur344333kd/45rrreew
```

so how i can get the new url path? using ***HtmlAgilityPack C# Winform***. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting `web.CaptureRedirect` to true, and by querying `web.ResponseUri`,

You can get the Url of the final request which actually downloaded the document:

Note: I am sending this UserAgent string, just like my Chrome Browser because server behavior may change depending on it.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36";

web.CaptureRedirect = true;

HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.google.com");

Console.WriteLine("Response retrieved from: {0}", web.ResponseUri);
```

The output is:

```
Response retrieved from: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
```

Comment: Thanks .. It's Working ... Is it possible to integrate google auth 2.0 with that link? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't have expertise in google auth. This works for any URL however. What is different with google auth?